# How to direct all variations of index and default to my 404 page?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So basically, I currently have this within my `.htaccess` file.

It redirects all variations of index and default to my home page. This is causing me some problems, and I would like to redirect all variations of index and default to my 404 page, being `404.html`

```
# Redirect all variations of index and default to www.domain.com/
# exception of index.php which should not be redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(default|index)\.(s?html?|pl|aspx?|cfm)[\s]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]
```

I tried doing this, but not to sure if it is the best way or not:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(default|index)\.(s?html?|pl|aspx?|cfm)[\s]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

How can I modify my code to do this? Do I also need to change `[R=301,L]` to a 404 instead somehow?

Comment: one line would be enough `RewriteRule your-regex-goes-here 404.html`

Comment: @Peter - But where does that tell the browser that it is a 404 error? It could just be interpreted as a normal redirect, and not a 404 error. Could you add `[L,R=404]` to the end of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `R=404` but in order to have your custom page erved, you need to use `ErrorDocuemnt`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(default|index)\.(s?html?|pl|aspx?|cfm)[\s]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

If you don't actually want a "404" error response, then you don't need the `R` flag at all:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(default|index)\.(s?html?|pl|aspx?|cfm)[\s]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /404.html [L]
```

Comment: Tried your first solution with the custom 404 page. Although it doesn't seem to link to it at all. I tried placing `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html` just above that bit of code, and also tried placing it within my `<IfModule>` tags. Still no luck. Any idea why?

Comment: @fizzix it says "Additionally there is a 500 server error". Check your logs to see what's causing that. It's possibly you may need to replace `^` in the rule's target to `!^404\.html` to prevent an inadvertent loop.